$f=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ implies $f\in H_0^1(\Omega)$
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Let $f\in C(\bar{\Omega})\cap H^1(\Omega)$ with $f=0$ on $\partial\Omega$.
Claim: Then $f\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ holds.
Since $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in $\|\cdot\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$ I am looking for a sequence $(f_n)\subset C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ converging to $f$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. 
Meyers-Serrin theorem garantuees the existence of a sequence $(g_n)\subset C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ converging to $f$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. Can I modify this sequence so that it lies in $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$? Or can I make any statements about the support of $f$? 
If $\Omega$ has smooth boundary the claim follows directly. But since the properties of the boundary can be abitrary I can not use Trace theorem.

May we assume that $\Omega$ is bounded?

@gerw No, $\Omega$ may be unbounded.

First, we can approximate $f$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ by functions with compact support. Indeed, we can multiply with a $1$-Lipschitz cutoff functions
$$
\psi(x) = \min\{1, \max\{0, M - |x|\}\}
$$
with $M > 0$ large enough.
This gives $g \in C_c(\mathbb R^d) \cap H^1(\Omega)$ with $g = 0$ on $\partial\Omega$ and $\| g - f \|_{H^1(\Omega)}$ arbitrarily small.
Next, we perform a shrinkage, i.e., for small $m > 0$, we set
$$
h(x) = \operatorname{sign}(g(x)) \max\{0, |g(x)| - m\}.
$$
This gives $h \in C_c(\Omega) \cap H^1(\Omega)$ and, if we choose $m$ small, $\| h - g\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$ becomes small.
Finally, since the support of $h$ has a positive distance to the boundary, we can use a standard mollification approach to approximate $h$ with a function from $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.

Hmm, this problem is somewhat interesting. My approach would go as follows, firstly construct the sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by applying the Meyers-Serrin theorem (so $g_n \in C(\Omega)$ and as $n \to \infty, g_n \to f$). Now we use the standard approach of approximating the domain $\Omega$ and thus boundary $\partial \Omega$ with a sequence of smooth domains $\Omega_k$, such that,
$$ \Omega_k \to \Omega \text{ as } k \to \infty \qquad \bigcup_{k>0} \Omega_k = \Omega$$
Generate a sequence of $\mu_k$ such that $\mu_k = 1, \text{on } \Omega_k$ and $\mu_k$ smoothly approximates the characteristics function near $\partial \Omega$. The sequence $\mu_k$ is approx $1$ on the domain, of course, if there is a discontinuity in transition from $\overline{\Omega}$ to $\partial \Omega$ that needn't be the case. As we go out of the $\partial \Omega$, $\mu_k$ smoothly decreases to $0$, thus ensuring that there are no discontinuities. The support of $\mu$ is compact. Let's redefine our original sequence such that $g_{n,k} = g_n \cdot \mu_k$. The constructed sequence converges to $f$ as $n,k \to \infty$, since $ || g_n - g_{n,k} ||_{H^1(\Omega)} = 0$, as $k \to \infty$. Hence there exists an approximation sequence $g_{k,n}$ such that $g_{k,n}$ has a compact support

How do you control the derivative when using your cut-off function?
